# How to clone or copy a list whose element is list, in python?

Tags: python, list

How to copy a list which is consisted of list type elements? I have used the method described in a similar question [how to clone a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) But it still doesn't work, as shown in picture below
[image: output of the original code]

Original code is

```
asd
a = [[]]
b = list(a)
for i in [1,2]:
    for j in b:
        j.append(i)
    print a
```

why would `a` change when `b` was changed? But I want to keep `a` from being changed.

Requirements: cannot import package such as `copy` since I met this problem in leetcode.com.

---

Finally, the answer is that I need a deep copy of list, that is 
`b = [c[:] for c in a]`. Notice: as @PM2Ring mentioned below at comment area, `b = [c[:] for c in a]` is only suited for a single level of nesting. For more complicated deep copy, look for phrase "deep copy". Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You're making a shallow copy. It's only copying the outer list, not the inner lists. Read the question you linked to again. Look for the phrase "deep copy".

Comment: if you print `print(a==b)` you will see that `a` and `b` are the same object. Like pointed above, you made a shallow copy.

Comment: The duplicate I linked (which is also the same post that you included in your question) features the deepcopy option as its fifth bullet point.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I just know from you that there is something called deep copy!! seems like I am still new to python....

Comment: @Arne No, it's not exactly the same, maybe as they said I need deep copy.

Comment: @Arne Ok, thank you, I'll try deep copy first.

Comment: BTW, `[c[:] for c in a]` isn't a deep copy, but it's deep enough because `a` only has a single level of nesting.

Comment: @PM2Ring Wow, I should add this message to my question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import copy

lis = [[1], [2]]

deep_list = copy.deepcopy(lis)
copy_list = copy.copy(lis)

print(deep_list is lis)
print(deep_list[0] is lis[0])
print(deep_list[1] is lis[1])

print(copy_list is lis)
print(copy_list[0] is lis[0])
print(copy_list[1] is lis[1])
```

In the above code `deepcopy()` creates a deep copy of the `list` so you and `copy()` creates a shallow copy. In case of `deepcopy()` the list's within the list will also be copied.

OUTPUT:

```
False
False
False
False
True
True
```

**EDIT:** Since you cant import library may be you can try below approach:

```
lis = [[1], [2]]

deep_list = []

for item in lis:
    deep_list.append(item[:])

print(deep_list is lis)
print(deep_list[0] is lis[0])
print(deep_list[1] is lis[1])
```

OUTPUT:

```
False
False
False
```

Comment: Correctly, I find this answer gives my desired outputs. But combined with @DirtyBit's slicing method, here I got a simple deep copy of list:`b = [c[:] for c in a]`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `copy`:

```
import copy

a = [[]]
b = copy.copy(a)    # b = a[:] using slicing is a lot faster
for i in [1,2]:
    for j in b:
        j.append(i)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Without package, using `slicing`:

```
a = [[]]
b = a[:]        # b = a.copy() Could also come in handy
for i in [1,2]:
    for j in b:
        j.append(i)
print(a)
print(b)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[1, 2]]
[[1, 2]]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import copy
....
b = copy.copy(a)
...
```

Comment: No, I met this problem from leetcode.com, so import new package is not allowed!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.